# How to sort cell in TableView base on the Alphabets ? ( CoreData ) ( Swift 3 )

Tags: xcode, swift3

[image]

how can I **sort the cells according Alphabets** and **ignore** the caps lock in coreData ?

***This is my code for Attempt Fetch***:

func attemptFetch() {

```
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()  // fetch the Item.


    // display it by Sort.

    let priceSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "price", ascending: true)
    let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: false)


    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]

    } else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [priceSort]

    } else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors =  [titleSort]

    }
```

Comment: `NSSortDescriptor`. But how do you fetch your data? What's your code?

Comment: just want to sort it according to the alphabets and ignore the caps Lock.

Comment: Please add the code where you r fetching the data

Comment: @YuOn Have you solved it, if not can you pleas so the fetch code of core data

Comment: @NiravD  **haven't solved it yet**, still struggle yesterday until now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make small change you need to use [`init(key:​ascending:​selector:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nssortdescriptor/1412495-init) of `NSSortDescriptor` instead of [`init(key:​ascending:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nssortdescriptor/1413572-init) when you want sort with `title` property.

```
let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare))
```

Comment: so i need to use **let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: , ascending: , selector: )**

Comment: @YuOn YES add that selector with it

Comment: @YuOn Have you check my answer properly it is `let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare))` not `let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true, selector: (NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(NSString)))`

Comment: **Thank You So Much !!**

Answer (score 0):

In your code to fetch the array of things(list), add the following code to sort in alphabetical order.

```
class func fetchAllThingsFromCoreData() -> [Thing] {

    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = MyCoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
    let request:NSFetchRequest<Thing> = self.fetchRequest()

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "thingName", ascending: true)]
    let myThingsCoreDataArray = try? context.fetch(request)
    return myThingsCoreDataArray ?? []
}
```